# Applet is not going to stop running

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Window1 extends JFrame {
private JFrame frame;
}
```

When I run this code I get an applet running which I don't want.
Any help is appreciated
Thx
Applet window

[image]

Comment: You are in Swing mode brother, why you extend JFrame if you don't want it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this, Is it stopping now?

```
import java.lang.Runnable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Window1 extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String... args){
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new java.lang.Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Window1 window = new Window1();
                window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                window.setBounds(200, 200, 400, 300);
                window.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: I knew that but I did'nt know how to exit the applet. Thx anyways